# JQuery Validation + Repeater + Panel - Validation Issue

Tags: jquery, validation, repeater, panel

I Have a repeater control and inside repeater control i have two linkbuttons (Show/Hide which will show and hide the panel) and also have a panel which contains textboxes (which takes first name and last name which are required fields). when i click on next button on my page validations are not triggered for the fields which are in hidden (panel). Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are hiding the panel on the server during a postback.

```
panel1.Visible = false;
```

If you hide the panel on the server, the markup for the textboxes never gets rendered, so the JQuery validation code will not see the textboxes.

Consider hiding/showing the panel using Jquery instead:

`$("#panel1clientId").show();` or

```
$("#panel1clientId").hide();
```

This way the panel markup is rendered but hidden from the user.